# Eclipse updates are extremely slow

Tags: eclipse, download, mirror

Today I tried to download EGit plug-in from eclipse.org, and waited an hour and nothing happened. I tried three more times, waited for three hours and stopped.

Then I tried to clone egit from the repository developers, but it began to clone at a rate of 5kbps.

Then I thought maybe something wrong with my Eclipse, and decided to download a new one. Eclipse main site opened with a super-slow speed (although bigger than 5kbps). I'm just afraid to download the installer at this speed.

Can anybody repoduce it? What should I do?

Comment: Which version of Eclipse are you using?  You have the option of downloading the zip file and unzipping it onto your Eclipse directories.

Comment: I reproduced this last night.... installing EGit actually stopped at 39% for many many hours. I then canceled it. What a waste of time !!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I am exepriencing the same problem. I am developing a plug-in that depends on a feature on the eclipse site. The downloading of that feature takes sometimes up to 30 minutes, even though it is quite small.

This is probably based on eclipse servers which we can't influence. There are  a couple bugs opened for this or similar issues. Feel free to comment on them to maybe get them fixed:

- https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=331634
- https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=162101
- https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=189380

and so on .. there are a bunch of those.

Answer (score 23):

You're right, Eclipse updating can be horribly slow, regardless of connection speed.

From what I can tell, this is because it checks a whole bunch of slow servers looking for updates every time you try and install something. You can disable this behaviour in the "Install New Software" dialog by unchecking the "Contact all update sites" option. I find that things go an awful lot faster then.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. Unchecking makes a huge difference

Comment: For speeding-up a regular update, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42941596/1800052)

Answer (score 4):

Check your firewall. In my case disabling McAfee  made it run smooth again.

Comment: Exact same problem and solution on AVG antivirus -- disabling for 15 minutes did the trick.

Answer (score 0):

I found some invalid links in Install/Update under Preferences, basically if you have any sort of invalid links which you may have added trusting in them to be update sites, it causes all downloads to be terribly slow. Go to Preferences>Install/Update and delete all your custom links that you added, you can specifically check the error log to tell you which links are invalid by running Update.